Query to get dates that have a 12 month gap between them
I have a table that contains PK and a created date:



PK
Created_Date




1
01/01/2007


1
01/02/2007


1
12/12/2008


2
15/02/2021


2
01/06/2022


2
02/06/2022



I am trying to bring back any records that have at least a 12 month gap between them. E.g for PK 1 I would expect to bring through the 1st and 3rd rows into the results. For PK 2 I’d expect to bring the 1st and 2nd rows.
I’ve tried a few different ways but not being able to compare all rows. One PK could have multiple created dates over a span of years.
Is there any way to do this without using a cursor?

hard to understand your question.. I think look up LAG functions.

This question is similar to: SQL Server query to find records with gap or 12 months or greater. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This fiddle shows the linked duplicate answer applied to your data. Results match your desired results. You might consider whether you need < or <= (more that 12 months" vs "at least 12 months".

From the question it is unclear why the combination of the 2nd row and the 3rd row is not a valid result, because the difference in dates is also larger than 12 months.
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(month,Created_Date, NextDate) MonthDifference
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *, 
      (SELECT MAX(Created_Date) FROM mytable m2 WHERE m2.PK=m1.PK) as NextDate
   FROM mytable m1) aliasForSubquery
WHERE Created_Date < DATEADD(MONTH, -12, NextDate)

output:



PK
Created_Date
NextDate
MonthDifference




1
2007-01-01
2008-12-12
23


1
2007-02-01
2008-12-12
22


2
2021-02-15
2022-06-02
16



DBFIDDLE
when you just want 1 row per PK,  you can do:
SELECT 
   PK,
   MIN(Created_Date),
   MAX(Created_Date)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY PK
HAVING DATEDIFF(month, MIN(Created_Date), MAX(Created_Date)) >= 12

output:



PK
(No column name)
(No column name)




1
2007-01-01
2008-12-12


2
2021-02-15
2022-06-02



see: DBFIDDLE
